# Running a docker container of a ubuntu image

Tags: docker

New to docker.

I'm trying to run a ubuntu image container.
after executing `docker run ubuntu` I don't find the container with `docker ps`.
I tried `docker ps -a`and I found the status of the container "Exited (0) 10 seconds ago".

But by running docker `docker run -itd ubuntu /bin/bash` I was able to get the container running.

I don't understand why the second worked and the first not, I tried to search but I wasn't able to find an answer.

Comment: I suggest you read through the docker documentation for [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) and read the description for each of the flags you specified `-i`, `-t`, and `-d`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker is not meant to only run a single instance of images like `ubuntu`, but its primary usage is to run applications.

When you run `docker run ubuntu`, it runs `ubuntu` and then exits because it has no any main process to run, so quits.

But if you run `docker run nginx`, it's shown in `docker ps`, why? Because `nginx` has a process to make this container running.

Try this: `docker run exec -it ubuntu top` and `docker run exec -it nginx top` and see the process with ID 1. See any differences? `top` in `ubuntu` container has PID 1, but in `nginx` container `nginx ...` command is the PID 1.

If you quit the `top`, your container kills and stops, but if you quit `top` in `nginx`, your `nginx` container keeps running. But whenever `nginx ...` command kills in `nginx` container, the `nginx` container will stop too.

I recommend using other online resources to read more about Docker.